# Issue when trying to run RSelenium in a rocker docker image

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile, geckodriver, rselenium

I'm trying to run RSelenium by extending a [rocker/r-ver](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/r-ver) docker image. My image looks like this (basically installing the required R-packages along with java and firefox):

```
# Use rocker/r-ver as the base image
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.1.2

# Install R packages
RUN R -q -e "install.packages('RSelenium')"
RUN R -q -e "install.packages('rvest')"
RUN R -q -e "install.packages('dplyr')"
RUN R -q -e "install.packages('ggplot2')"
RUN R -q -e "install.packages('purrr')"
RUN R -q -e "install.packages('scales')"
RUN R -q -e "install.packages('plotly')"

# Install firefox and java
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    unzip \
    curl \
    xvfb \
    wget \
    firefox \
    default-jre default-jdk && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Start R and assign rsDriver
CMD R -e "library(RSelenium);rdriver <- rsDriver(browser = 'firefox');remDr <- rdriver[['client']]"
```

The image builds fine (`docker build -t myimg --platform linux/amd64 .` ) but when i run it (`docker run --platform linux/amd64 myimg` ) i get the following error, which seems to be triggered when trying to assign the `rdriver` from the `rsDriver` function:

```
(...)
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
Creating directory: ~/.local/share/binman_geckodriver/linux64/0.33.0
Downloading binary: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/downl...

Downloading binary: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/downl...

Creating directory: ~/.local/share/binman_geckodriver/linux64/0.32.2
Downloading binary: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/downl...
 
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
Error in (function (platform, file, processed, chmod)  : 
  ~/.local/share/binman_geckodriver/linux64/0.33.0/geckodriver-v0.33.0-linux64.tar.gz.asc does not appear to be a zip or tar file.
Calls: rsDriver ... do.call -> <Anonymous> -> Map -> mapply -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

How can i fix this??